# Websockets in Vue/Vuex (how to receive emissions from server)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io, vuex

So until now I just socket.io-client to do communication to a WebSocket in my Vue component.
Now I am adding Vuex to the project and declared a Websocket like this

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: 'http://192.168.0.38:5000',
}));

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

1) Should i have stuff like emitting some messages in the component themselves now or in the store?

2) Before I introduced the changes I could do something like this:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
      console.error('connected to webSocket');
      socket.emit('my event', { data: 'I\'m connected!' });
    });

socket.on('my response', function(data){
      console.log('got response');
      console.log(data.data);
    });
```

When sending the "my event", the flask server would respond with "my response". Now I am trying the same thing from a component after the changes like this.

```
    this.$socket.emit('my_event', { data: 'I\'m connected!' });
    console.error('send to websocket ');

    this.$options.sockets.my_event = (data) => {
      console.error('received answer ');
      console.error(data);
    };
```

The my_event reaches my flask server however I don't get the response receiving to work. What am I doing wrong?
Also because I was asking about whether I should put this in the component or the store, I found stuff like this for the store:

```
SOCKET_MESSAGECHANNEL(state, message) {
      state.socketMessage = message
    }
```

The explanation was "So, for example, if your channel is called messageChannel, the corresponding Vuex mutation would be SOCKET_MESSAGECHANNEL" and it is from this site https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-socketio/.

I think I don't really get what a channel is at this point. Is the my_response I emit from the flask server also a channel?
Thanks for your help in advance!

**EDIT:** So now I am trying to listen and emit to a websocket from my store. For this I tried the following: In main.js I have this part:

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: SocketIO('http://192.168.0.38:5000'),
  vuex: {
    store,
    actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
    mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
  },
}));
```

Then in my store.js I have the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
    title: 'title from vuex store',
    isConnected: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count += 1;
    },
    emitSth(state) {
      this.sockets.emit('my_event', { data: 'I\'m connected!' });
      console.log(state.count);
    },
    SOCKET_my_response(state) {
      state.isConnected = true;
      alert(state.isConnected);
    },
    SOCKET_connect(state) {
      state.isConnected = true;
      alert(state.isConnected);
    },
  },
});
```

And in my component I have this script:

```
export default {
  name: 'ControlCenter',
  data() {
    return {
      devices: [{ ip: 'yet unknown' }], // placeholder so line 12 does not throw error before actual device info fetched
      thisDeviceIndex: 0,
      currentLayoutIndex: 0,
      layouts: [],
    };
  },
  computed: mapState([
    'title',
    'count',
  ]),
  components: {
    DNDAssign,
    FirstPage,
  },
  methods: {
    // mapMutation helper let's us use mutation from store via this instead of this.$store
    ...mapMutations([
      'increment',
      'emitSth',
    ]),
    incrementMutation() {
      this.increment();
    },
    emitEvent() {
      this.emitSth();
    },
    // some other stuff here
  },
  created() {
    // inital fetching of layouts
    console.log('fetching layouts from backend');
    this.getAllLayouts();

    console.log(this.$socket);
  },
};
```

I also have a button for the triggering of the emit which is

```
<b-button
type="button"
variant="success"
v-on:click="emitEvent()"
>
emit event
</b-button>
```

The connected in the store gets triggered, **however I get the following errors for the emitting**:

- "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"
- "Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

Also I am not sure about the naming in the mutations. If I have this mutationPrefix, **shouldn't it be enough to just use connect instead of SOCKET_connect?**

Comment: No, the prefix is used to distinguish normal action and socket action, so if you have `SOCKET_` as the prefix, and on the server you emit `someMessage`, it's gonna call vuex actions with name `SOCKET_someMessage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are using Vue-Socket.io version 3.0.5>, uninstall it and install version 3.0.5

```
npm uninstall vue-socket.io
npm install vue-socket.io@3.0.5
```

then lock the version in `packege.json`: `"vue-socket.io": "3.0.5"`, latest update seems to breaks the library, read more [here](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/issues/250#issuecomment-625723614)

Now to receive events from socket.io server, you can do:

```js
this.sockets.subscribe("my response", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

or if want put listener on component level, you need to add `sockets` object on the component export, for example:

```js
export default {
    ...
    sockets: {
        "my response": function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Since you are not using Vuex Integration on the VueSocketIO, you dont need to put additional function in store mutation. If you want to use Vuex integration on VueSocketIO, you need to add `vuex` object when declaring the VueSocketIO class.

Here's the basic example for `main.js`

```js
// Set Vue to use Vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

// Create store
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      someData: null
  },
  getters: {},
  actions: {
      "SOCKET_my response"(context, data) {
          // Received `my response`, do something with the data, in this case we are going to call mutation "setData"
        context.commit("setData", data);
      }
  }
  mutations: {
      ["setData"](state, data) {
          state.someData = data; // Set it to state
      }
  }
});

// Set Vue to use VueSocketIO with Vuex integration
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: 'http://192.168.0.38:5000',
  vuex: {
      store,
      actionPrefix: "SOCKET_"
    }
}));

new Vue({
  router,
  store
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

If you need example on Vuex Integration, you can check [my example app](https://github.com/VincentJonathan/nobar-vue) that uses Vue and Vue-Socket.io with Vuex integration.te

Comment: thanks a lot Owl for your extensive answer! I tried out the different ways, you suggested. The only thing I am wondering now is, when to use which of these options. Is it e.g. just a personal preference, if  i do it like in the first snippet or if I do it on component level? Or is there a reason when to put it where? Also in which cases does it make sense to add it to the vuex store?

Comment: I think it just depends on what the event used for and how's your Vue app structured, for example if you are building a chat app, and you have the own view for the Chat (Chat.vue), then i would use component level listener. First snippet is dynamic listener, which means you can .subscribe & .unsubscribe to start & stop listening to an event, unless you need to do .unsubscribe, I personally wouldn't use this since Component level looks more cleaner and structured for me. And use Vuex Integration only if you use Vuex store to store your data (e.g chat list) so you can mutate your data easier.

Comment: Ah that definitely makes sense, thanks again for taking the time! I think since in my application I want to get some data from the websocket and this data should be used in multiple components, that the vuex store solution might be best then. I looked at the documentation and your code but I unfortunately still don't get how to write the thing for my_response or also just connect in the vuex store. I will add the details of what I tried to my original question and would be glad for further help

Comment: I just got the msg "Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members" when updating, so I hope this will be visible to others soon as I really feel stuck with this

Comment: Updated my answer to help you get started.

Comment: oh now I see, the problem, i edited your answer instead of my post. I am so sorry, just a total newbie here

Comment: For emitting from the store I used the following line btw **Vue.prototype.$socket.emit('my_event', { data: 'I\'m connected!' })**;

Comment: Hi Owl, Not able to access your repository. I am also facing a problem to connect multiple sockets.